# How to recode dataframe values to keep only those that satisfy a certain set, replace others with "other"

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

I'm looking for a concise solution, preferably using `dplyr`, to clean up values in a dataframe column so that I can keep as they are values that match a certain set, but others that don't match will be recoded as "other".

### Example

I have a dataframe with names of animals. There are 4 legit animal names, but other rows contain gibberish rather than names. I want to clean the column up, to keep only the legit animal names: `zebra`, `lion`, `cow`, or `cat`.

#### Data

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)

real_animals_names <- sample(c("zebra", "cow", "lion", "cat"), size = 50, replace = TRUE)
gibberish <- do.call(paste0, Map(stri_rand_strings, n = 50, length=c(5, 4, 1),
                                 pattern = c('[a-z]', '[0-9]', '[A-Z]')))

df <- tibble(animals = sample(c(animals, gibberish)))

> df

## # A tibble: 100 x 1
##    animals   
##    <chr>     
##  1 zebra     
##  2 zebra     
##  3 rbzal0677O
##  4 lion      
##  5 cat       
##  6 cfsgt0504G
##  7 cat       
##  8 jhixe2566V
##  9 lion      
## 10 zebra     
## # ... with 90 more rows
```

#### One way to solve the problem -- which I find annoying and not concise

Using *dplyr 1.0.2*

```r
df %>%
  mutate(across(animals, recode,
                "lion" = "lion",
                "zebra" = "zebra",
                "cow" = "cow",
                "cat" = "cat",
                .default = "other"))
```

This gets it done, but this code repeats each animal name twice, and I find it clunky. Is there a cleaner solution, preferably using `dplyr`?

---

**EDIT GIVEN SUGGESTED ANSWERS BELOW**

Since I do like the readability of `dplyr::recode`, but dislike having to repeat each animal name twice; and since the answers below utilize `%in%` – could I incorporate `%in%` in my own `recode` solution to make it simpler/more concise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `base` solution:

```
keep_names <- c('lion', 'zebra', 'cow', 'cat')

within(df, animals[!animals %in% keep_names] <- "other")
```

A `dplyr` option with `replace()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(animals = replace(animals, !animals %in% keep_names, "other"))
```

With `recode()`, you can use a named character vector for unquote splicing with `!!!`.

```
df %>%
  mutate(animals = recode(animals, !!!set_names(keep_names), .default = "other"))
```

***Note:*** *`set_names(keep_names)` is equivalent to `setNames(keep_names, keep_names)`.*

Comment: First, it's necessary to specify `rlang::set_names()` because `purrr` has `set_names()` too. Second, I ended up twisting your solution a bit to work with `mutate(across(...))`, but the principle remains the same: `df %>% mutate(across(animals, recode,!!!rlang::set_names(keep_names), .default = "other"))`

Comment: @Emman actually `rlang::set_names` and `purrr::set_names` is completely the same thing. `set_names` is originally in `rlang` and `purrr` imports it into itself. In your question you have attached `tidyverse`, so `purrr` is also attached. You don't need to specify `rlang::set_names()` because `set_names` from `purrr` will be called.

Comment: I see. But still, when I omit `rlang::` then I get an error: `Error in set_names(keep_names) : 
  1 argument passed to 'names<-' which requires 2`. But when explicitly calling `rlang::set_names` it runs without error.

Comment: @Emman I think you have attached `magrittr`, right? `magrittr` also has a function named `set_names` and it masks `set_names` from `rlang` and `purrr`. In this situation, you need to specify `rlang::` or `purrr::`.

Comment: yup, that's true :)

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the animals that you need as it is and turn the rest to `"Others"` :

```
library(dplyr)

keep_names <- c('lion', 'zebra', 'cow', 'cat')

df %>% mutate(animals = ifelse(animals %in% keep_names, animals, 'Others'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked preferably for a dplyr solution but here a `data.table` solution (note that I changed the `tibble()` call to `data.table()`):

```
library(stringi)
library(data.table)

real_animals_names <- sample(c("zebra", "cow", "lion", "cat"), size = 50, replace = TRUE)
gibberish <- do.call(paste0, Map(stri_rand_strings, n = 50, length=c(5, 4, 1),
                                 pattern = c('[a-z]', '[0-9]', '[A-Z]')))

df <- data.table(animals = sample(c(real_animals_names, gibberish)))

keep_names <- c("lion", "zebra", "cow", "cat")
df[!animals %in% keep_names, animals := "other"]
```