# Converting some dataframe values to NA: values to convert are column-dependent, and given in a separate list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

In a dataframe, I want to turn some values to `NA`. Which values should become `NA` is column-dependent. This column-based value specification is given in a separate list object. I want to write a function that will accept:

1. a dataframe to be cleaned up
2. a vector specifying which columns to clean
3. a list specifying each values are ok for each column

And will return a clean dataframe, where undesired values became `NA`. While such a task can be achieved with a `for` loop, I'm trying to figure out whether there's a simpler iterative way to do it. I typically like `tidyverse` solutions, but will be happy with any idea.

### Example Data

In the following dataset, each column has its own set of valid values that should remain, and the rest should become `NA`.

```r
library(tibble)

set.seed(2020)

## generate random strings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42734863/6105259
sample_strings <- function(n = 5000) {
  a <- do.call(paste0, replicate(5, sample(letters, n, TRUE), FALSE))
  paste0(a, sprintf("%04d", sample(9999, n, TRUE)), sample(letters, n, TRUE))
}

df <-
  tibble(id = 1:40,
         color = sample(c(1:5), size = 40, replace = TRUE),
         political = sample(c(sample(c("republican", "democrat", "green_party", "libertarian"), size = 20, replace = TRUE),
                              sample_strings(20))),
         religion_status = sample(c(sample(c("secular", "traditional", "religious", "atheist", "agnostic"), size = 20, replace = TRUE), 
                                    sample_strings(20)))
         )

## # A tibble: 40 x 4
##       id color political  religion_status
##    <int> <int> <chr>      <chr>          
##  1     1     4 republican fzwue3975k     
##  2     2     4 republican mgxoe2220e     
##  3     3     1 democrat   secular        
##  4     4     1 republican secular        
##  5     5     4 aibcg6459y oqnfv1461t     
##  6     6     2 aedqi0739y ufhua9648n     
##  7     7     1 zgvox0771x agnostic       
##  8     8     5 democrat   traditional    
##  9     9     2 republican atheist        
## 10    10     2 oxgge5657l nktsl2136o     
## # ... with 30 more rows
```

Knowing which values should be kept in which column comes from the following list:

```r
var_mapping_list <- list(preferences = list(age = list(originType = "NumberQuestionPage", 
    originIndex = 6L, title = "what is your age?", valueDescriptions = NULL), 
    political = list(originType = "QuestionPage", originIndex = 7L, 
        title = "what is your political affiliation?", valueDescriptions = list(
            republican = "I have voted most of my life to the republican party", 
            democrat = "I have voted most of my life to the democratic party", 
            other = "other")), religion_status = list(originType = "QuestionPage", 
        originIndex = 9L, title = "how do you define your religiousness level? ", 
        valueDescriptions = list(secular = "I don't practice any religion although I do belong to one", 
            traditional = "I'm observant and keep some of the practices", 
            religious = "I practice a religion", other = "other")), 
    color = list(originType = "QuestionPage", title = "which color do you like the best", 
        valueDescriptions = list(`1` = "red", `2` = "blue", `3` = "yellow", 
            `4` = "pink", `5` = "orange")), pet = list(originType = "QuestionPage", 
        originIndex = 0L, title = "do you have a pet? ", valueDescriptions = list(
            yes = "yes", no = "no"))))
```

### One variable for example

Say that I want to clean up `df$political`. To know which values to keep, I will first go to:

```r
var_mapping_list$preferences$political$valueDescriptions

## $republican
## [1] "I have voted most of my life to the republican party"

## $democrat
## [1] "I have voted most of my life to the democratic party"

## $other
## [1] "other"
```

My rule is that all options **except for** `other` are the valid values for the corresponding column in `df`.

So this means that in `df$political`, only `republican` and `democrat` should remain, and the rest should turn `NA`.

Thus, an example workflow for just `df$political` would be:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)

vec_political_values_to_keep <-
  var_mapping_list$preferences$political$valueDescriptions %>%
  bind_rows %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = tidyselect::everything(), 
               names_to = "option_key", 
               values_to = "description") %>%
  filter(option_key != "other") %>%
  pull(option_key)
 

df %>% 
  mutate(political = recode(political, !!!rlang::set_names(vec_political_values_to_keep), .default = NA_character_)) ## https://stackoverflow.com/a/63916563/6105259


## # A tibble: 40 x 4
##       id color political  religion_status
##    <int> <int> <chr>      <chr>          
##  1     1     4 republican fzwue3975k     
##  2     2     4 republican mgxoe2220e     
##  3     3     1 democrat   secular        
##  4     4     1 republican secular        
##  5     5     4 NA         oqnfv1461t     
##  6     6     2 NA         ufhua9648n     
##  7     7     1 NA         agnostic       
##  8     8     5 democrat   traditional    
##  9     9     2 republican atheist        
## 10    10     2 NA         nktsl2136o
```

---

**I want to scale the above to any variable of interest in `df`.**

### Desired Output

Specifying the vector

```r
colnames_to_clean <- c("color", "political", "religion_status")

[1] "color"           "political"       "religion_status"
```

Should return the following dataframe:

```r
##       id color political  religion_status
##    <int> <int> <chr>      <chr>          
##  1     1     4 republican NA             
##  2     2     4 republican NA             
##  3     3     1 democrat   secular        
##  4     4     1 republican secular        
##  5     5     4 NA         NA             
##  6     6     2 NA         NA             
##  7     7     1 NA         NA             
##  8     8     5 democrat   traditional    
##  9     9     2 republican NA             
## 10    10     2 NA         NA
```

I'll be grateful for any help with this!

Comment: To be honest, your question is too long and includes extraneous information.  Your real question is how to parse the survey data in a semi-automated way to recode the answers.  But it's not really clear what you really want to extract from `var_mapping_list`, because your example for it doesn't even have green_party, but elsewhere in your code you do.  Try to focus your question more.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I've tried revising the question several times to make it clearer, but probably not enough. `green_party` *does* appear in the data, but *because* it's not in `var_mapping_list`, we know that `green_party` doesn't belong to the data and should therefore become `NA`. The entire purpose of `var_mapping_list` is to let us know which values should remain in `df`.

Comment: I've edited once again, I hope it's clearer. I'd appreciate any feedback if it requires further clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility.
First you put the valid values in a `tibble`.

```
new_list <- tibble(
  name  = names(var_mapping_list$preferences),
  x = var_mapping_list$preferences
) %>%
  mutate(all_vals = map2(x, name, ~ names(.x$valueDescriptions))) %>%
  select(-x)
```

This has the advantage that you now can easily work with valid values inside the tidyverse.
Second, you join the valid values and check if the current value is a valid value:

```
df %>%
  gather(name, val, -id) %>%
  left_join(new_list, by = "name") %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(val = map2_chr(val, all_vals, ~if_else(.x %in% setdiff(.y, "other"), .x, NA_character_))) %>%
  select(-all_vals) %>%
  spread(name, val)

# A tibble: 40 x 4
      id color political  religion_status
   <int> <chr> <chr>      <chr>          
 1     1 4     republican NA             
 2     2 4     republican NA             
 3     3 1     democrat   secular        
 4     4 1     republican secular        
 5     5 4     NA         NA             
 6     6 2     NA         NA             
 7     7 1     NA         NA             
 8     8 5     democrat   traditional    
 9     9 2     republican NA             
10    10 2     NA         NA             
# ... with 30 more rows
```